Does this system of differential equations have a solution?
In the process of solving a physics problem (motion of a of a rope of mass $M$ and length $L$ with $l_0$ hanging off the edge) I arrived at the following system of differential equations: $$\begin{aligned}
\dot{l}^2+(l-L)\ddot{l}&=0 \\
l\  \ddot{l}+\dot{l}^2&=gl \\
l(0)&=l_0 \\
\dot{l}(0)&=0
\end{aligned}$$
Subtracting the equations, I obtained $$\ddot{l}=\frac{g}{L}l$$ which I easily solved to obtain $$l(t)=l_0 \cosh{\left( t\ \sqrt{\frac{g}{L}} \right)} $$
which is the correct solution, as far as I know.
On a whim, I decided to plug back the solution into the system of equations and found, to my surprise, that this function doesn't satisfy either of the two equations. A quick desmos plot shows that while my function does satisfy third equation, it doesn't satisfy either of the original ones. What exactly has happened here? Does the system of differential equations even have a solution?

You have no system of differential equations... You have two differential equations and, for some reason, you believe that they have the same solution.
By subtracting the equations, you concluded that, if they have the same solution, the solution must be $l(t)= l_0 \cosh(\cdots)$. If this is not a solution to the original equations, we simply conclude that the equations do not have the same solution.
My suggestion is that you review the rational behind the derivation of the differential equations.
In the figure below you can see in blue the solution to
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot \ell^2(\ell -L)\ddot \ell=0\\\ell(0) =\ell_0, \dot \ell(0)=0
\end{cases}
$$
and in orange the solution to
$$
\begin{cases}
\ell \ddot \ell + \dot\ell^2=0\\\ell(0) =\ell_0, \dot \ell(0)=0
\end{cases}
$$


I'm sorry, I don't follow. Why is this not a valid system of differential equations? Is it not true that a system of equations is one or more equations that must be satisfied simultaneously? And I assumed that they have the same solution because they describe the same function. You're right in that the way in which I arrived at them must be reviwed though

When you have a system of differential equations you have more than one unknown function... If you take the first equation and the initial conditions, this is already sufficient to fix the solution. The same goes if you take the second equation and the initial conditions. When you put the two equations together with the initial conditions, either they have the same solution an you have a solution to your "system" or they don't have the same solution (your case).

I see. So this is akin to an overdetermined system of linear equations that does not have a solution?

@VulgarMechanick, yes, it is like an overdetermined system.
